# Is it possible to use "for a few days" with present simple?

Tags: present-tense

is it possible to use for a few days with present simple :
I read in a movie with subtitles for a few days I  miss the cat, should it be  I've missed the cat for a few days if it is ongoing situation or recently finished or I missed the cat for a few days if it belongs to the past

Comment: What movie?  What was the context?  "For a few days, I miss the cat" looks very odd but perhaps there is context that makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

The present simple for verbs that aren't "stative" verbs has a "narration" effect - you'd use this tense if you were recording actions in a log or describing what someone is doing in real time.

A device someone might use when recounting past events is to pretend we have gone back in time.  If we identify a past point in time, and then we use present as though "now" is that past point in time, we pull the reader into a story of recounted events.

> Ok, I'll tell you how this all began.  It started on the first day of May in 2010.  I wake up that morning, I eat breakfast, and suddenly I hear a knock on the door.  When I open the door, I see an old lady there, and she says her name is Margaret.

So we may pull the reader back to a time in the past in this fashion, and want to describe events that occur over a longer period of time.  "For a few days {present simple}" works here.

> Ok, I'll tell you how this all began. It started on the first day of May in 2010. I wake up that morning, I eat breakfast, and suddenly I hear a knock on the door. When I open the door, I see an old lady there, and she says her name is Margaret.  She tells me she lost her cat and asks if I saw the cat anywhere.  I tell her no.  For a few days I look everywhere for the cat, but her pet was nowhere to be found.

Outside of this, it likely won't work though.